# problems with jekyll frontmatter

Tags: jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I'm trying to use `jekyll`.  I'm running `elementary 0.4.1 loki`. My `index.html` currently consists of this (with --- above and below layout:default):

`index.html`:

```
---
layout: default
---
```

My understanding is that jekyll should read that and look to my layouts folder where it will find my `default.html` file and replace index with that file.

I run jekyll serve, but when I go to `localhost:4000` it just shows: `index.html` `--- layout: default ---`

I've restarted the jekyll server a few times.  I've tried Chromium and Firefox.  The `default.html` file seems fine.  I found more complex problems solved but they don't seem to deal with my issue.

There is something I have done wrong that is stopping jekyll from reading my `index.html` properly.

Can anyone tell me what it is? 
I must be doing something stupid but I can't find it.

Apologies if I am making mistakes in my question format. Any help?

Comment: please, add your code.

Comment: Be sure that your text editor is encoding file in utf-8 with NO BOM.